# Check if local server is reachable by ip (wifi)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, connection

In developing my app I face the following problem:

I need to check if a remote data service (running on IIS) is available from the phone. This requires the phone to be on the same network (same IP range). How do can I check if the phone has wifi, and if the remote server is reachable?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can check wifi status with this property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation.iswifienabled(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Oke, thanks, that still leaves me with how can i check if the host is reachable?

Comment: Try to [ping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx) it.

Comment: @Romoku - WP8 doesn't include that portion of .NET. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.net.networkinformation(v=vs.105).aspx  There isn't an exposed API to do basic pings to my knowledge. WP8 now supports some Win32 networking API though so you could use do some low level work to make your own.

Comment: I have tried to ping it with code samples from MSDN, but i also came to the conclusion that it was not available for windows phone 8. So, what is the closest alternative.